# Sorting a hash with nil as a key

Tags: ruby, null

I'm going through this tutorial: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/jsattend.html

In iteration 7, step 3 we get to sort a hash, called state_data, which has nil as a key. The proposed solution is:

```
state_data = state_data.sort_by{|state, counter| state unless state.nil?}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working on ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]. For example:

```
~% irb
>> things = { nil => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c" }
>> things.sort_by { |k, v| k unless k.nil? }
ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 2 failed
    from (irb):6:in `sort_by'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/jacopo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

The same goes with the equivalent:

```
>> things.sort_by { |k, v| k if k }
ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 2 failed
    from (irb):3:in `sort_by'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/jacopo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

In the tutorial's case, since it's sorting on the state two letter code, a possible solution is:

```
state_data = state_data.sort_by{|state, counter| state.nil? ? "ZZ" : state }
```

which is clearly a hack.

What's the Ruby-way to deal with this?

Comment: I think there's a bit of code smell if I got a nil as a hash key. I'd want fix that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line

```
state_data.sort_by { |state, counter| state unless state.nil? }
```

is effectively equivalent to a simple `state_data.sort`, because `(state unless state.nil?) == state` in any case. What you could do is to seperate the proper keys from the `nil` keys and only sort the former:

```
state_data.select(&:first).sort + state_data.reject(&:first)
```

In the more general case, you can also define a custom comparison function like this:

```
def compare(a, b)
  return a.object_id <=> b.object_id unless a || b
  return -1 unless b
  return 1  unless a
  a <=> b
end

state_data.sort { |a, b| compare(a.first, b.first) }
```

By quickly looking at this, you see that it's pretty ugly. In fact, you should rather rethink your choice of data structure here. `nil` keys don't seem very sensible to me.

**UPDATE:** From looking at the tutorial you linked to, I take it that there is a lot of suboptimal information in there. Take a look at the following piece of "Ruby", for example:

```
ranks = state_data.sort_by{|state, counter| counter}.collect{|state, counter| state}.reverse
state_data = state_data.sort_by{|state, counter| state}

state_data.each do |state, counter|
  puts "#{state}:\t#{counter}\t(#{ranks.index(state) + 1})"
end
```

You could write this much more cleanly and get the same result:

```
rank = state_data.sort_by(&:last)
state_data.sort.each do |data|
  puts "%s:\t%d\t(%d)" % [*data, rank.index(data) + 1]
end
```

The author also recommends code like

```
filename = "output/thanks_#{lastname}_#{firstname}.html"
output = File.new(filename, "w")
output.write(custom_letter)
```

While the Ruby idiom would be:

```
filename = "output/thanks_#{lastname}_#{firstname}.html"
File.open(filename, 'w') { |f| f.write(custom_letter) }
```

This shows that the author doesn't seem to be very apt in Ruby. Thus, I can't recommend that tutorial.

Comment: @Jacopo: It just occured to me that a simple `states.select(&:first).sort + states.reject(&:first)` could also be sufficient in your special case.

Comment: *yikes*, that `File.new` stuff from the tutorial isn't even bad Ruby, it's bad in *any* language with a Unix-inspired IO library (C, C++, Java, Perl, Python, you name it), since it's leaking a file descriptor.